# Iterate items in array through NodeJS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, contentful, contentful-management

I am trying to find a solution to creating multiple assets in **Contentful** using the [contentful-management](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/assets/assets-collection/create-an-asset/console/js) API.

The **nodeJS** script to achieve a single creation of an asset is

```
const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: '<content_management_api_key>'
})

client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.getEnvironment('<environment-id>'))
.then((environment) => environment.createAssetWithId('<asset_id>', {
  title: {
    'en-US': 'Example 1'
  },
  file: {
    'en-US': {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      fileName: 'example1.jpeg',
      upload: 'https://example.com/example1.jpg'
    }
  }
}))
.then((asset) => asset.processForAllLocales())
.then((asset) => asset.publish())
.then((asset) => console.log(asset))
.catch(console.error)
```

Which is quite simple and easily implemented. However, when wanting to create multiple assets, this does not work.

After many hours looking for a documented way to achieve this, with no avail, I came to

```
const contentful = require('contentful-management');
const assets = require('./assetObject.js');

async () => {
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    accessToken: '<content_management_api_key>'
  });

  const space = await client.getSpace('<space_id>');
  const environment = await space.getEnvironment('<environment-id>');
  const createdAssets = await Promise.all(
    assets.map(
      asset =>
        new Promise(async () => {
          let cmsAsset;

          try {
            cmsAsset = await environment.createAssetWithId(asset.postId, {
              fields: {
                title: {
                  'en-US': asset.title
                },
                description: {
                  'en-US': asset.description
                },
                file: {
                  'en-US': {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                    fileName: asset.filename,
                    upload: asset.link
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          } catch (e) {
            throw Error(e);
          }
          try {
            await cmsAsset.processForAllLocales();
          } catch (e) {
            throw Error(e);
          }
          try {
            await cmsAsset.publish();
          } catch (e) {
            throw Error(e);
          }
        })
    )
  );
  return createdAssets;
};
```

**assetObject.js**

```
[
 {
    link: 'https://example.com/example1.jpg',
    title: 'Example 1',
    description: 'Description of example 1',
    postId: '1234567890',
    filename: 'example1.jpeg'
  }, ... // Many more
]
```

This, when running, produces no errors, nor does it do anything. What have I done wrong? Is this the method I should use?

Comment: @xrobert35 has the right answer but I had one thing to add: when you process the asset you might want to check that the `asset.fields.file["en-US"].url` exists before publishing. The existence of `asset.fields.file["en-US"].url` is the only indication you'll get that the processing of the file associated with the asset for that locale has been completed.

Comment: The SDK `processForAllLocales` function also has two options you can tweak if needed to allow for the asset processing to complete if running into errors: `options.processingCheckWait` and `options.processingCheckRetries`. See https://contentful.github.io/contentful-management.js/contentful-management/5.3.2/Asset.html#.processForAllLocales for details

Comment: Thank you @CharlieC. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new promise need to be "resolved" and "rejected" so for me the code should look like

```
 const createdAssets = await Promise.all(
    assets.map(
      asset =>
        new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {    
          try {
            const cmsAsset = await environment.createAssetWithId(asset.postId, {
              fields: {
                title: {
                  'en-US': asset.title
                },
                description: {
                  'en-US': asset.description
                },
                file: {
                  'en-US': {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                    fileName: asset.filename,
                    upload: asset.link
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            await cmsAsset.processForAllLocales();
            await cmsAsset.publish();
            resolve(cmsAsset);
          } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
          }
        })
    )
  );
  return createdAssets;
```

Hop it can help